# Duplicate call to CoroutineExceptionHandler

Tags: android, kotlin

I call two launch in turn, the first throws an error, and the second ends in a second.

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
    Log.d("myLogs", "$exception was handled in Coroutine_${context[CoroutineName]?.name}")
} 
        
val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default + handler)
        
scope.launch(CoroutineName("1")) {
    Integer.parseInt("a")
}
        
scope.launch(CoroutineName("2")) {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

One handler call is expected, but there are two

```
2020-07-08 19:31:51.840 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a" was handled in Coroutine_1
2020-07-08 19:31:52.840 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a" was handled in Coroutine_2
```

Comment: what happen if you use SupervisorJob() instead of Job()?

Comment: @Hooman handler is called only once.

Comment: Why do you expect one handler call? It's behaving correctly, so we have to understand your reasoning to be able to explain why it's incorrect.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am waiting for one call, because the exception is thrown only in one place - in the first coroutine.

Comment: I think we need to see more context of where this code is called. It's suspicious that the second invocation happens one second after the first, the same length of time that the second coroutine sleeps its thread.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It is suspicious that the second invocation is taking place, because there is no error in the second coroutine

Comment: it is because when you use Job() if one of child launches fails, all children fails too. if it is not your intended behaviour use SupervisorJob.